# Appwrite function build fails to install dependencies even as I specifically define them

Tags: python, bash, docker, ubuntu, appwrite

I have been trying to upload a function that allows me to turn a CSV into a JSON file. The code works but when I try to deploy it to my instance of Appwrite, the build fails.

Here is my function:

```
from appwrite.client import Client
from appwrite.services.storage import Storage
import pandas as pd


def main(req, res):
    file_id = res.payload["fileId"]
    bucket_id = res.variables.BUCKET_ID
    api_key = res.variables.API_KEY
    client = Client().set_endpoint(res.variables.ENDPOINT).set_project(res.variables.PROJECT_ID).set_key(api_key)
    storage = Storage(client)
    binary_csv = storage.get_file_view(bucket_id, file_id)
    data = BytesIO(binary_csv)  # type: ignore
    df = pd.read_csv(data)
    value = df.to_json(orient="records")
    return res.json({
        "message": "Success <200>",
        "payload": value
})
```

My requirements.txt:

```
appwrite
numpy>=1.23.0
pandas>=1.5.0
```

On the build failure log, this is where it fails

```bash
Docker Error:   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 
  ╰─> [ lines of output]
      Collecting setuptools>=.0
        Downloading setuptools-65.5.0-py3-none-any.whl ( MB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ /1.2 MB  MB/s eta :00:00
      Collecting wheel
        Downloading wheel-0.37.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl ( kB)
      Collecting Cython<,>=.32
        Using cached Cython-0.29.32-cp310-cp310-musllinux_1_1_x86_64.whl ( MB)
      Collecting oldest-supported-numpy>=
        Downloading oldest_supported_numpy-2022.8.16-py3-none-any.whl ( kB)
      Collecting numpy==.6
        Downloading numpy-1.21.6.zip ( MB)
           ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ /10.3 MB  MB/s eta :00:00
        Installing build dependencies: started
        Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
        Getting requirements to build wheel: started
        Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
        Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
      Building wheels for collected packages: numpy
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): started
        Building wheel for numpy (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
        error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

It is using the wrong version of numpy too. Later in the response it shows the actual pip command which does use the right version.

```bash
Collecting appwrite
  Downloading appwrite-1.1.0.tar.gz (13 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): started
  Preparing metadata (setup.py): finished with status 'done'
Collecting numpy>=1.23.0
  Downloading numpy-1.23.4.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.7/10.7 MB 18.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
  Getting requirements to build wheel: started
  Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
  Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
Collecting pandas>=1.5.0
  Downloading pandas-1.5.1.tar.gz (5.2 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 5.2/5.2 MB 115.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
  Installing build dependencies: started
  Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, you can't use pandas in Appwrite Functions because installing numpy seems to require some OS packages not available in the open runtime. You can follow [this](https://github.com/appwrite/appwrite/issues/1037) issue for updates on this.

For your basic CSV to JSON task, how about you use the standard [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) package instead of pandas?